# React hook form passing value to onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

How to correctly pass data to onSubmit function `data` property?
When i click + i see the numbers changing but when clicking Submit button it does not pass data to `onSubmit` function, this can seen in console.log it's always 0

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import { InputAdornment, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export const InputNumberStepper = () => {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    register,
  } = useForm();
  const [val, setVal] = useState<number>(0);
  console.log(' ~ val:', val);

  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    console.log(' ~ data:', data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name="stepper"
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
          console.log(' ~ value:', value);

          return (
            <TextField
              {...register('stepper')}
              id="stepper"
              value={val}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment
                    position="start"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setVal(val - 1);
                      // onChange(value - 1);
                    }}
                  >
                    -
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment
                    position="end"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setVal(val + 1);
                      // onChange(value + 1);
                    }}
                  >
                    +
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xmyqch?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really using React Hook Form properly. You are managing the field state in your component instead of letting React Hook Form store and manage the form state.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { InputAdornment, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function App() {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    register,
  } = useForm({ defaultValues: { stepper: 0 } });

  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    console.log(' ~ data:', data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name="stepper"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => {
          return (
            <TextField
              {...register('stepper')}
              id="stepper"
              {...field}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment
                    position="start"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setValue('stepper', parseInt(field.value) - 1);
                    }}
                  >
                    -
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment
                    position="end"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setValue('stepper', parseInt(field.value) + 1);
                    }}
                  >
                    +
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```